# Android Build Tools keep ProGuard from removing unused appcompat library classes

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

Here's a part of my `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

There's nothing in `proguard-rules.pro` but I noticed a file named `aapt_rules.txt` was generated which has something like this:

```
# view res/layout/abc_action_menu_item_layout.xml #generated:17
-keep class android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView { <init>(...); }

# view res/layout/abc_expanded_menu_layout.xml #generated:17
-keep class android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ExpandedMenuView { <init>(...); }

# view res/layout/abc_list_menu_item_layout.xml #generated:17
# view res/layout/abc_popup_menu_item_layout.xml #generated:17
-keep class android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ListMenuItemView { <init>(...); }

# view res/layout/abc_screen_toolbar.xml #generated:27
-keep class android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer { <init>(...); }

# view res/layout/abc_action_mode_bar.xml #generated:19
# view res/layout/abc_screen_toolbar.xml #generated:43
-keep class android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView { <init>(...); }

# view res/layout/abc_screen_toolbar.xml #generated:17
-keep class android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout { <init>(...); }

# view res/layout/abc_screen_content_include.xml #generated:19
-keep class android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout { <init>(...); }

# view res/layout/abc_screen_simple_overlay_action_mode.xml #generated:23
-keep class android.support.v7.internal.widget.FitWindowsFrameLayout { <init>(...); }

# view res/layout/abc_screen_simple.xml #generated:17
-keep class android.support.v7.internal.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout { <init>(...); }

# view v11/res/layout-v11/abc_screen_content_include.xml #generated:19
-keep class android.support.v7.internal.widget.NativeActionModeAwareLayout { <init>(...); }

# view res/layout/abc_action_mode_close_item_material.xml #generated:17
# view res/layout/abc_search_dropdown_item_icons_2line.xml #generated:27
# view res/layout/abc_search_dropdown_item_icons_2line.xml #generated:37
# view res/layout/abc_search_dropdown_item_icons_2line.xml #generated:48
# view res/layout/abc_search_view.xml #generated:116
# view res/layout/abc_search_view.xml #generated:128
# view res/layout/abc_search_view.xml #generated:38
# view res/layout/abc_search_view.xml #generated:60
# view res/layout/abc_search_view.xml #generated:97
-keep class android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintImageView { <init>(...); }

# view res/layout/abc_screen_simple.xml #generated:25
# view res/layout/abc_screen_simple_overlay_action_mode.xml #generated:32
-keep class android.support.v7.internal.widget.ViewStubCompat { <init>(...); }

# view res/layout/abc_action_menu_layout.xml #generated:17
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView { <init>(...); }

# view res/layout/abc_activity_chooser_view.xml #generated:19
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat { <init>(...); }

# view res/layout/abc_search_view.xml #generated:78
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$SearchAutoComplete { <init>(...); }

# view res/layout/abc_screen_toolbar.xml #generated:36
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar { <init>(...); }
```

Which obviously keeps everything used by XMLs in the support library even if those XMLs are not used at all. And the codes that are kept again keeps all the resources from being skipped using `shrinkResources true`. And the apk size increased a lot even nothing in the support library is used. The same thing goes with other libraries.

So is there a way to customize `aapt_rules.txt` or do something like that to remove those unused code and resources? (or do I need to open an issue for this somewhere?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see there are comments in aapt_rules.txt. Beside each kept class there are corresponding layout files that referenced this class. Like that:

```
# view res/layout/abc_list_menu_item_layout.xml #generated:17
# view res/layout/abc_popup_menu_item_layout.xml #generated:17
-keep class android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ListMenuItemView { <init>(...); }
```

If you remove the layout file from build process this line will desappear and class will not be kept. The class will be shrinked if it's not actually used somewhere.

So how can we remove layout file from appcompat library? I can see few options, none of them is perfect but they work.

1. You can just remove file from sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7\version\appcompat-v7-version.aar. Enough for testing, bad for production because the same file may be used in some other projects. I tried and it works.
2. Put fake file with the same name into your project. Name conflict will happen. Build process will prefer your fake file because project files have higher priority. This way file from appcompat will be ignored. I tried and it works.
3. Probably you can make some fancy gradle script that removes unwanted files during the build process. I haven't tried that.

(shrinkResources option doesn't help because aapt_rules.txt is generated BEFORE shrinkResources is actually involved.)

I hope somebody will suggest a better way to do that

After doing that all unwanted lines were gone from aapt_rules.txt. But it saved me about 100 KB from the final apk size. So not big deal for me. But in your case results may be different.

Comment: The second one sounds like a solution. :-)

Comment: By the way have you tried the latest Android build tools? They said [they've fixed it](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=156938).

Comment: @Mygod Not sure what they mean. The same issue still seems to be there. The same unused files still get into aapt_rules.txt. Have just tried with the latest build tools - SDK tools 25.1.7, Build Tools 24, Android Gradle Plugin 2.2.0-alpha4, appcompat library 23.3.0.

Comment: Maybe you have to use Android Studio to enable this feature?

Comment: @Mygod I do use Android Studio, still the same.

Comment: Hey maybe they meant using Jack tool chain. Could you try that?

Comment: @Mygod Have just tried Jack. Seems to be still the same.

Comment: Still an issue today.  All the unused appcompat junk (not just layout, but also drawables) is bloating my APK from ~250kb to ~950kb.  Will try some of these later in the week.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [`sbt-android`](https://github.com/scala-android/sbt-android) to build, you can manually override `proguardConfig` like this:

```
proguardConfig in Android := List("-dontobfuscate",
  "-dontoptimize",
  "-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile",
  "-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable",
  "-verbose",
  "-flattenpackagehierarchy",
  "-dontusemixedcaseclassnames",
  "-dontpreverify",
  "-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/simplification/cast,!field/*,!class/merging/*,!code/allocation/variable",
  "-keepattributes *Annotation*",
  "-dontnote android.annotation.**",
  "-dontwarn android.support.**",
  "-dontnote android.support.**",
  "-dontnote scala.ScalaObject",
  "-dontnote org.xml.sax.EntityResolver",
  "-dontnote scala.concurrent.forkjoin.**",
  "-dontwarn scala.beans.ScalaBeanInfo",
  "-dontwarn scala.concurrent.**",
  "-dontnote scala.reflect.**",
  "-dontwarn scala.reflect.**",
  "-dontwarn scala.sys.process.package$",
  "-dontwarn **$$anonfun$*",
  "-dontwarn scala.collection.immutable.RedBlack$Empty",
  "-dontwarn scala.tools.**,plugintemplate.**",

  "-keep class scala.collection.SeqLike { public java.lang.String toString(); }",

  "-keep class android.support.v7.view.menu.ListMenuItemView { <init>(...); }",
  ...
)
```

Answer (score -2):

The following definition was written in the getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), which is one of the default proguard setting in the directory of {android-sdks}/tools/proguard

```
 # The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
 # Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
 # platform version.  We know about them, and they are safe.
 -dontwarn android.support.**
```

So, it keeps everything.

Useless code can be passed by another proguard file, {android-sdks}/tools/proguard/proguard-android-optimize.txt, which use default 5 
turns to optimize code( **-optimizationpasses 5** ).

Comment: But dontwarn doesn't keep anything. It just literally stops ProGuard from warning a method is missing.

Comment: -keep  class android.support.v4.app.** {*;}
-keep  interface android.support.v4.app.** {*;}

-keep  class android.support.v7.** {*;}
-keep  interface android.support.v7.** {*;}

Comment: @Mygod,  thank you for right comments, yes, the followings keeps everything about support library V4 and V7